# WCF generate proxies classes with DataContract and DataMember attribute

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that calls another SOAP service (that I don't have control over). I would like to return the dependent services proxy types to my services clients.

I have done this manually by adding DataContract and DataMember attributes to the proxy classes.

Is there anyway to automate applying these attributes to these proxy classes?

Comment: Do you control both services?

Comment: No, I don't own the other service.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I was having was that when using add service through visual studio 2015, it passes a flag that generates IPropertyChangedNoify on the objects which when trying to reuse a proxy class that has been generated from an external source this would cause WCF test client to throw an exception when adding a service that was returning such type.

My Semi solution so far was to use svcutil manually.

```
svctuil /namespace:*,<MyNameSpace> path-to.wsdl /out:MyClass.cs
```

I'm now able to add my service that uses an external proxy class as a return type.

The next problem I'm having now is that WCF test client won't let me call/test the method, because I'm using this type. WCF hover note says "WCF test client doesn't support this method because it uses 'MyCustomType'". And the method is grayed out.

I'm getting closer, to the solution.